# How to connect from client js to server js send and fetch data using node js

Tags: node.js

Using `node.js` I started server, I open browser and it loads index file in that page, a button is there. If I click on that button I need to connect to server and fetch data from MySQL and display it on some division just like synchronous call from AJAX to PHP.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected to your database then simply using express to fetch your data as Express is used for Web applications.